# Port not added to iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm trying to add port `7777/udp` to `iptables` on CentOS 7.

The command I use is:

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27020 -j ACCEPT
```

But no matter what, the port is not addded.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27020
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27015
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:interwise
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:cbt

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The two ports listed are created in the same script and are regularly added.
Why these two port are OK but 7777 is not?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are either `interwise` or `cbt` equal to `7777` by any chance?

Comment: I have no idea, I did not add the last two. How can I check?

Comment: A quick search on Google yielded cbt = 7777. So I assume the name is just encoded when I add 7777?

Comment: The output of `iptables-save` might be better for debugging (or restoring the firewall rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### first view the iptables properly using the command :-

### iptables -L -n

-n will show port number instead of service associated with that port. This will clear things. use echo $? if iptables command is not showing any error. The result is zero means command is running fine.